# WP Dynamic Content in Modal Window Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Help! I screwed up and have a very cranky client on this one...

I've created a modal window inside of my WP php template files that says "when they click on this link for more information, pop up this modal window that shows a script sample."

The page it's on is a whole long list of products, so each product is its own custom post with custom fields that are calling all of the product information, including the text that needs to display in the modal window.

The CSS I'm using works in that it does activate the modal window when the link is clicked, BUT it's only activating the first product item, so that if a customer is clicking on the 14th one down they're still only seeing the content for the first product item.

What do I need to change so that each modal window shows the appropriate content? I feel like a dummy. :(

Here's the code I have that powers that little snippet:

```
<style type="text/css">
.black_overlay{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 370px;
height: 420px;
background-color: black;
z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
opacity:.80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
width: 330px;
height: 380px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: white;
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto;
}
</style>
<?php query_posts( array(
 'post_type'    =>'product',
 'orderby' => 'title',
   'order' => 'ASC',
  'showposts' => 9999999,
 'tax_query'    => array(
     array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'Group',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array( 'books','video','audio-book' ),
        'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
    ),
)
) ); ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><img src="images/question.png" alt="What is on the recording?" border="0" /></a>
    <div id="light" class="white_content"><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
    <p><b>This is an excerpt from the script:</b><br /><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'sample_script', true ); ?></p></div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and what was actually happening was that ALL the posts were popping up onclick, and because they were absolutely positioned, they were stacking on top of each other and creating the illusion of only the first window popping up every time. Might be worth checking for you as well.